# What is the default height of a edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

In my xml code have one spinner and edittext both height set to `wrap_content`. But the spinner height is less than the edittext. My goal is to set the both of the height to same.

I tried to apply the `Widget.AppCompact.EditText` style to spinner, but its not working. Im currently using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` as a base theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your `onCreate` method:

```
editText.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=spinner.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height=editText.getHeight();
            spinner.layoutParams=layoutParams;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx working perfectly.. Is there any way to do through xml?

Comment: Well, if you want to do it in xml then give fix height to both(ediText and spinner).

Answer (score 0):

To have same height, use a `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its occupying the half screen.. I just want to set the default edittext height to spinner

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to achieve what you want with `ConstraintLayout`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="200dp" // Change to what width you prefer
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/edit_text"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Im using <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#EEEEEE" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#000" />
</shape> as background for edittext and spinner but they are not looking same.